# get data from table and fill text box depending on select value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Suppose there is a table student:

mysql> select * from student;

```
+----+-------------+
| id | studentname |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |   jack      |
|  2 |   mack      |
|  3 |   rock      |
|  4 |   john      |
+----+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

i have a view file that contains a form.
Here i have a list where teacher gives marks to the students, so in the case I get data from table student and fill a text box....
After the user fills the form, Marks tables will be updated.
form look like below:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | studentname |  Marks |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |   jack      |        |
|  2 |   mack      |        |
|  3 |   rock      |        |
|  4 |   john      |        |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

after entry data form look like below:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | studentname |  Marks |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |   jack      |   5    |
|  2 |   mack      |   4    |
|  3 |   rock      |   6    |
|  4 |   john      |   8    |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

after click submit data will insert into marks table.

Comment: This reads like a brief. If you want a quote for how much this work will cost, try Freelancer.com.

Comment: What is your question? Just write a MySQL `UPDATE` statement that updates the `Marks` table from the form input. There are many tutorials on the web about how to do MySQL queries from PHP, and how to submit tables as forms.

Comment: What have you done so far?